# Making a loop in python and abaqus (calling in/outputs from each other)

Tags: python, abaqus

I am new in both Abaqus and Python, that's why I need some advice on my problem. I know, I am not supposed to put the whole problem but in my case I need to know which approach is better; scripting the whole thing in Python or using ABAQUS PDE and scripting in ABAQUS.

The problem:

I am trying to simulate a simplified milling process. The tool moves on the work-piece in a straight line from point A to B increment by increment with an initial depth of cut (DOC). At each increment I want to call the output from abaqus (Thickness in this case) and read it in my python script as an input and then manipulate DOC value. The output of my python script is calculation of a new cutting force based on the new and manipulated DOC value. This is where my "for" and "if" loops come in until it satisfies me with an acceptable error.

For more information: I don't want to simulate the whole process, therefore my load here is a distributed force (in Z-direction only) attached to the bottom of my tool (which has a circular area).

My questions:

Since I want to run the script through GUI bunch of times to make sure everything is OK and at the end I want to run it with noGUI command:

1. Which approach is better? scripting in ABAQUS or doing it completely in python?
2. Is there any code that help me to delete (remove) elements which are in the overlapped area between my tool and work-piece geometries at the end of each increment? (second picture).
3. Is it possible to re-mesh my work-piece once the loop for each increment ends?

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me through this even if it is just the names of the commands I need. (I can search how they work myself).

Thank you.

[The cutting process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpafp.jpg)

[Element deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IdOu.jpg)

[The work-piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weurX.jpg)

[The cutting force idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdBlJ.jpg)

[Implicit milling](https://gofile.io/?c=q3zXNO)

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve problems with a scope this large. As such, I think this is too broad a question for SO. Instead, I suggest you come up with a process you would like to implement, show us your effort, and we can help you achieve your goal when you run into trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MattP. To begin with, my current problem is how to make that deletion elements works weather by codes or abaqus/CAE. I have attached the .MDB file of my work. I am thinking of a process just like "Merge/cut Instance" in Assembly Module but in each increment.